# Matlab: connected components analysis

Tags: matlab, raster, connected-components

From the following binary raster:

```
R = [0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1;
     0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0;
     0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
     0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
     1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1];
```

I would like to remove all 4-connected components with less than 3 pixels.

Initially, the amounts of connected components are evaluated:

```
CC = bwconncomp(R,4);
L  = labelmatrix(CC);
IC = CC.PixelIdxList;
np = cellfun(@numel, IC);
```

Subsequently, 4-connected components with less than 3 pixels are found:

```
idxs = find(np < 3)
```

However, the final attempt to remove the connected components from the input raster R is not successful:

```
R(IC{idxs}) = 0;   %Result: 4-D double
```

The output raster is converted to "4D" matrix. This may be caused by incorrect work with the output cell of cells, but I am not sure...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have 4 connected component with less than 3 pixels. `idxs` will have 4 elements. `IC{idxs}` will be a comma-separated list with 4 elements, which when used as indices index a 4D array. MATLAB will increase the size of `R` to accommodate the indexing you're doing. Instead, loop over the elements of `idxs`, and do the indexing for each object individually. Or, you could concatenate the various `PixelIdxList`s: `idx = cat(1,IC{idxs}); R(idx) = 0;` (I'm not sure if you need to do `cat(1,...)` or `cat(2,...)`).

Comment: @Cris Luengo: Thank you very much for your advice and explanation.